# Sometimes IIS underutilizes a multicore processor

Tags: asp.net, iis, multicore, stress-testing

I have faced strange behavior of my ASP.Net application on the server (IIS7 on Windows Server 2008 x64, processor Xeon Quad).

The web application is the simple page which about one second calculates some math, and then displays result. That is it almost does not consume a network, a disk, memory, but completely uses processor resources.

The following phenomenon appears at load testing: IIS7 utilize processor no more than on 25% and not for the world does not wish to utilize it more. This 25% are equal to one core, but spread out on all four according to task manager performance tab. On the other computer (IIS7, Win 7, Quad) all works as well as should: the processor is utilized on all of 100%.

For each of behavior variants (peak loading of 25% and 100% on 4 core processors) I have found on 2 computers. The similar situation is described [here](http://forums.iis.net/t/1155383.aspx). What can cause such behavior?

Comment: Is the workerprocess configured to use more than 1 process?

Comment: "Maximum worker processes" = 1. But in other computer with 4 cores and "Maximum worker processes" = 1 the CPU usage = 100%.

Answer (score 2):

> This 25% are equal to one core, but
>   spread out on all four according to
>   task manager performance tab.

Reality check: when you use up one core, the CPU scheduler will move the load between cores before 2008 R2. Staring with 2008 R2 it will keep it on one core to actually move the other cores into deep sleep.

So, what you see is basically an application that uses one CPU core. Point.

> What can cause such behavior?

Either your code, or your request generation (well, together with your code) make sure that the requests are serialized and not handled in parallel.

During load testing... do you accept / keep the session cookie (like: ONE) and in your asp.net page do you have session state enabled? This would serialize all page requests to the one session in memory and is one very likely culprit. Another one is doing "stupid" things in code the result in a block and make the algorithm effectively single threaded - but this can no be evaluated without a lot more information from you on how you program and what you effectively do. For example I have seen a bunch of monkeys once code an online shop using ONE database connection (to not overload the database) that was kept in the aplication object and using the lock / unlock methods there to effectively turn their asp application into a single threaded thing. This was obvious - but there are a lot of other things that can go wrong. The questions basically are:

- Are you by configuration / test scenario doing something to force IIS to serialize (which would be among web farming settings or bad usage of session state)?
- Do you do anything within the pages that is effectively locking them to single threaded?

IIS per se answers requests through work items (i.e. uses a LOT of threads) unless it HA to serialize them (sessions only are ever assigned to ONE thread at a time, so a second request for the same session is serialized).

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it's spread out. More likely the algorithm is not parallelised and so the code runs in a single core.

Comment: The algorithm really is not parallel. But load testing pages requests are parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I have understood, that on those 2 computers where loading was 100%, 32 bit Windows has been installed. On the same 2 computers, where peak loading was 25% - 64 bit.  But customisation change "Enable 32 bit applications"=true has not helped.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is using multiple worker processes and you are sure that your load testing software is issuing requests in parallel, then something in your application is likely becoming serial.

This is actually pretty common (we do a lot of load testing for our customers) - it could be as simple as a database pool with a size of one or as complex as some shared resource being locked at some level deep within the application or within a library the application is using. We've seen cases where the first step in serving an application page opens a transaction that is not committed until the page is done. If that transaction is locking a table that is needed for the same purpose by every other page, then only one page request can be serviced at a time.

Good luck hunting down the problem - be sure to let us know what you find!

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been solved after installation of fresher OS. "*Windows Server 2008 Enterprise SP1 (c) 2009*" instead of "*Windows Server 2008 Standard SP2 (c) 2007*".